# Connect Microsoft Flow to Outlook Groups

Tags: outlook, ms-office

I've figured out that Microsoft Flow allows me to do some IFTTT-like things to automate stuff around the house, I would however like to have it post messages to an Outlook Group as well to notify me of things it does. I know there is the Outlook Connectors for Groups, which does exactly what I want, but it is not currently available on Microsoft Flow as an option. How do I integrate the two? Or is this not possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard http action available within Microsoft Flow to do this. You just create a new connector at the developer dashboard first, and then you set up an http POST action in the form of a JSON file that forms a 'card' to the url/endpoint you get in the developer dashboard. You can find the options and syntax for this JSON file [here](https://dev.outlook.com/Connectors/Reference).